# How to import bak file to Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I just created new `SQL` server `database` on `Azure portal`. My target now is to `import` my `local database` which I generated `.bak file` . Could you please follow me up how to `import` it there? I was searching over net but I see everywhere mentioning about `backpacks files` . How to `import bak file?` Is there any way? I saw that `Azure SQL Database` does not currently support that functionality. How to then `import database` and `data` there in most easiest way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the standard `.bak` file.

You are going to have to export your database to a `.bacpac` file. 
See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-export-bacpac-ssms/)

and then import that `.bacpac` file into the azure sql server.
see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-import-bacpac-ssms/)

NB: Remember to add your IP address to the azure sql server firewall rules.

For more info on migrating your DB to azure see here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/

Comment: Or use the 'SQL Azure migration wizard' to copy everything to azure

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a database on local machine then you can migrate it directly on Azure using SQL Management Studio.

view my answer with screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41526042/908936

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the .bak file to restore a local database on your local device, if database is not already on your local device then first create the database and then use the .bak file to restore.
2. In Microsoft SQL Management Studio in Tasks select Export Database to Azure.

That is it :)